# Fortify and third-party libraries

Tags: fortify

I am trying to understand in the new version of Fortify SCA 17.10, why the scan defaults to excluding third-party libraries? I found this [article](https://techbeacon.com/third-party-libraries-are-one-most-insecure-parts-application) and it seems any open source library you use, it would be in your best interest to get these issues fixed by poll request.  I noticed some of the findings I get from a Fortify scan are typically false positives, is this why now Fortify excludes third-party libraries?  Is there a legitimate reason for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been [crossposted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44930883/3248253) where it has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, I don't **know** why they did this, but knowing developers and their attitude towards third party software here's my speculation:

1. Developers tend not care about the whole system, they want to know about the bugs in the code **they** wrote.
2. Scanning third party code takes time.  Why take time to discover things that the average developer doesn't care about?

Should developers care about the total product's security?  Of course.  But the typical developer isn't evaluated on that, (s)he is evaluated on the code they produce.

Comment: Some static analyzer vendors do not allow sharing the findings because this will limit their customer base.